# Confused in one of the boundary conditions in Electrodynamics

Tags: electromagnetism, boundary-conditions

I am confused about the derivation of the boundary condition relating the perpendicular components of magnetic field across the boundary.

In my optics course, the instructor used the fact that $\epsilon$ might vary spatially. And so he used this equation

$$ \vec{\nabla} \cdot(\vec D)=\rho$$

And then took a closed surface to do the integral which resulted in
$\epsilon_{1}E_{1}^\perp = \epsilon_{2}E_{2}^\perp$.

---

Now for the magnetic component he used similar approach and used this equation
$$\vec{\nabla}\cdot{\vec B}=0~~~~~~~ ......(1)$$

And got $B_{1}^\perp=B_{2}^{\perp}
             $

But then I divided the equation (1) both sides by $\mu$ and then got the relation
$$\mu_{1}B_{1}^{\perp}=\mu_{2}B_{2}^{\perp}$$

Now when I asked about this derivation to my instructor he himself got confused and had no answers why the above result is not true.

**So can someone here point out why it's not true ?**

Comment: How the heck is this a homework question. This is something that I got confused into myself !!

Comment: In what differential equation have you divided both sides by $\mu$ (_which_ $\mu$?) to get this result?

Comment: I don't think this question needs any edit. I just want to know why I can't apply the second method to reach the last relationship.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen

Comment: You can find a note here https://basics.altervista.org/jump-conditions-for-em-field/

Answer (score 1):

$\mu^{-1}\vec\nabla \cdot \vec B = 0$ does not imply $\vec \nabla \cdot (\mu^{-1}\vec B)=0$. In moving $\mu$ inside the divergence operator, you are assuming that $\mu$ is uniform. Note that
$$\require{cancel}
\vec\nabla \cdot(\mu^{-1}\vec B)=\vec\nabla (\mu^{-1})\cdot \vec B+\mu^{-1}\cancelto{0}{ \vec\nabla\cdot \vec B}=\vec\nabla (\mu^{-1})\cdot \vec B$$
The right-hand side is not zero in general because $\mu$ is a function of position.

At the interface of two media with different permeabilities, $\mu$ has a large discontinuity. This means it has a very large gradient here: in fact if we are assuming the two media are separated by an abrupt boundary, $\vec \nabla \mu^{-1}$ goes to infinity and must be described by a [delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function). You can integrate and apply Gauss' theorem to $\vec\nabla \cdot(\mu^{-1}\vec B)=\vec\nabla (\mu^{-1})\cdot \vec B$ if you'd like, but carefully dealing with the integral of the right-hand side will still produce $B_1^\perp=B_2^\perp$.

Answer (score 0):

From integral form of Maxwell's equations, you get

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  d_{n2} - d_{n1} & = \sigma \\
  b_{n2} - b_{n1} & = 0 \ ,
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
being $\sigma$ the surface charge density. If surface charge density is zero, and considering a surface between two linear isotropic non-dispersive media, described by the constitutive equations $\mathbf{d}_k = \varepsilon_k \mathbf{e}_k$ and $\mathbf{b}_k = \mu_k \mathbf{h}_k$, it's possible to write

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  d_{n2} & = d_{n1} \\
  b_{n2} & = b_{n1} \ ,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

or

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  \varepsilon_2 e_{n2} & = \varepsilon_1 e_{n1} \\
  \mu_2 h_{n2} & = \mu_1 h_{n1} \ .
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}